# How are C libraries installed?

Tags: c, linux, libraries

sorry for stupid question, but I have been writing programs in other languages and now that I am starting to get into C, I would like to know this.

I am on Arch (sorry to be that guy, I think it matters), and pretty new to it, but I need to install library.
Are libraries packages, or should I get them from somewhere like github? What is propper procedure?
Library in question is libgimp/gimp.h

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Depends entirely on the library itself. Some don't even come precompiled but in source form. Some are statically linked, so they will become part of your executable

Comment: Installing from a package manager is easier. You can also download the source (e.g. from github) and compile yourself, but usually you only need to do this if you need full control over which version you get.

Comment: It seems the package [`gimp`](https://archlinux.org/packages/extra/x86_64/gimp/) includes the library.

Comment: https://linoxide.com/install-packages-arch-linux/ tells you how packages are install on arch, this would include libraries.  Under the covers, a library usually a dynamic library named .so is copied to one of the directories that the linker search for libraries. symlinks are created, etc.  On linux, your own libraries either goes in /usr/local/lib/ or in an app specific library and LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable is updated to include that path.   There are other libraries that you load at run-time with the app which doesn't have a naming standard.

Comment: libgimp/gimp.h is a c header file, not a library, although it's usually associated with a matching library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run:

```
$sudo pacman -S gimp
```

And then:

```
$ ls -l usr/include/gimp-2.0/libgimp/
usr/include/gimp-2.0/libgimp/gimp.h
usr/include/gimp-2.0/libgimp/gimp_pdb.h
usr/include/gimp-2.0/libgimp/gimp_pdb_headers.h
usr/include/gimp-2.0/libgimp/gimpaspectpreview.h
usr/include/gimp-2.0/libgimp/gimpbrush_pdb.h
usr/include/gimp-2.0/libgimp/gimpbrushes.h
usr/include/gimp-2.0/libgimp/gimpbrushes_pdb.h
usr/include/gimp-2.0/libgimp/gimpbrushmenu.h
usr/include/gimp-2.0/libgimp/gimpbrushselect.h
usr/include/gimp-2.0/libgimp/gimpbrushselect_pd
...
```

You will have to provide the compiler flag

```
-I/usr/include/gimp-2.0
```

And the linker flag:

```
-lgimp-2.0 -lgimpbase-2.0
```

Note: Always include files this way:

```
#include <libgimp/file_name.h>
```

e.g.:

```
#include <libgimp/gimp.h>
```

**Update:** As requested by another user, I am attaching the instructions in terms of [pkg-config](https://people.freedesktop.org/%7Edbn/pkg-config-guide.html) (not a big user myself but it's a great tool):

```
$ pkg-config --cflags gimp-2.0
-I/usr/include/gimp-2.0 -I/usr/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0 -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/include/libpng16 -I/usr/include/libmount -I/usr/include/blkid -I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/lzo -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/harfbuzz -I/usr/include/pixman-1 -I/usr/include/gegl-0.4 -I/usr/include/gio-unix-2.0 -I/usr/include/json-glib-1.0 -pthread -I/usr/include/babl-0.1 
$ pkg-config --libs gimp-2.0
-lgimp-2.0 -lgimpmath-2.0 -lgimpconfig-2.0 -lgimpcolor-2.0 -lgimpbase-2.0 -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lcairo -lgegl-0.4 -lgegl-npd-0.4 -lm -Wl,--export-dynamic -lgmodule-2.0 -pthread -lglib-2.0 -ljson-glib-1.0 -lgio-2.0 -lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0 -lbabl-0.1
```

So you may just pass that to your compiler:

```
GIMP_INCLUDES=$(pkg-config --cflags gimp-2.0)
GIMP_LIBS=$(pkg-config --libs gimp-2.0)
g++ myfile.cpp $GIMP_INCLUDES myfile.o
g++ myfile.o $GIMP_LIBS -o main
```

Comment: If arch ships a .pc file for this library please rephrase your answer in terms of pkg-config.